# Matplotlib fontproperties only changing first axis tick

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

When I use the matplotlib fontmanager library to change the axis ticks to a custom font only the first tick is updating. Can anyone help figure out why is this?

I can loop through the tick labels in the axis and set the font for each one, but I'm wondering why the fontproperties argument isn't working.

Example code below, results in only the first x label having the correct font and size and the rest of the ticks with default formatting.

```
tick_prop = fm.FontProperties(fname="Jack.ttf", size=25)

ax.set_xticks([0,1,2])
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels,fontproperties=tick_prop)
```

Comment: Hard to tell what the issue is from such a short code snippet.  i.e. what is `tick_prop`?

Comment: have a look at ``rcParams``, specifically ``rcParams['font.family']``, which can be set to ``tick_prop.get_name()``

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and I can  reproduce this. I do not know what the underlying reason for this is. The code shown below will recreate this problem for me. Only the first tick on the x- and y-axis have the new font, the other do not.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import font_manager as fm

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

########
# Dummy data for reproducibility
N = 100
x = np.linspace(1,N,N)
ydata = np.random.randn(N)
ydata = np.cumsum(ydata)

yticks = [i*(max(ydata)-min(ydata))/3 + min(ydata) for i in range(4)]
xticks = [10*i for i in range(11)]

yticks_labels = ['very cold', 'chilly', 'nice', 'hot']
xticks_labels = xticks


########
# Generate plot
path = '/home/path/to/font/myfont.ttf'
tick_prop = fm.FontProperties(fname=path, size=25)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))

ax.plot(x,ydata, color='xkcd:red')

ax.set_yticks(yticks)
ax.set_xticks(xticks)

ax.set_yticklabels(yticks_labels, fontproperties=tick_prop)
ax.set_xticklabels(xticks_labels, fontproperties=tick_prop)


plt.show()
```

[image: first tick has correct font and size, rest is back to normal]

What works for me is the following approach, where I use the path to the font explicitly (use Path() to generate path from string). I have marked all new parts with comments.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import font_manager as fm

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path        # new part
# Dummy data
N = 100
x = np.linspace(1,N,N)
ydata = np.random.randn(N)
ydata = np.cumsum(ydata)

yticks = [i*(max(ydata)-min(ydata))/3 + min(ydata) for i in range(4)]
xticks = [10*i for i in range(11)]

yticks_labels = ['very cold', 'chilly', 'nice', 'hot']
xticks_labels = xticks


# Generate plot
path = '/home/path/to/font/myfont.ttf'
tick_prop = fm.FontProperties(fname=path, size=25)

fpath = Path(path) # new part 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))

ax.plot(x,ydata, color='xkcd:red', label='temperature')

ax.set_yticks(yticks)
ax.set_xticks(xticks)

ax.set_yticklabels(yticks_labels, font=fpath, fontsize=25) # new part
ax.set_xticklabels(xticks_labels, font=fpath, fontsize=25) # new part

ax.legend(prop=tick_prop)


plt.show()
```

[image]
This solution comes with its own problems. I do not like it, but it works. If anyone could give an explanation, or an alternative, I would be more than happy.